# how to adapt JavaScript container to allow more than one possible selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following JavaScript checks to see if the Dialog popup container is the Element clicked and only closes the dialog if an element outside of the container is clicked.

How can this be adapted to allow for more than 1 ID or Class?

```
// Used to close Layout Dialog
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#optionsModal");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
        $("#page-cover").hide();
    }
});
```

Could var container be an array of id/class names instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to your selector...

```
var container = $("#optionsModal, #anotherIdElement");
```

Comment: @JoJo -- Yeah, the comma lets you have multiple selectors.

Comment: @JoJo - it's an `AND` operator, not an `OR` . . . it will act on both.  So, if both elements exist on the same page, you will need to do the comparison differently, since it will return multiple element references.  You need to check to see if the target is in that collection, rather than being equal to it.